# Casting in equals method

Tags: java, casting, equals

I have a question about overriding the `equals` method in Java. In my book, I have the following example:

```
public class Dog{
     private String name;
     private int age;

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof Dog)) return false;
    Dog other = (Dog) obj;                    ---> confused here
    if(this.name.equals(other.name) && (this.age == other.age) {
     return true;
    }
    else {
     return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why why have to cast the reference to the `Dog` reference. If that reference is not of type `Dog` we return false. Why all the hassle with casting it ?

Comment: Don't forget to obj == null. And not related with your question but you could just return this.name.equals(other.name) && (this.age == other.age)

Comment: Since this Equals is accepting only one parameter and this is an override of Dog class so this equals expects the object of type Dog. if you pass another type of object then will always return the false this is the part of extreme programming which is to make sure to avoid any expected runtime failure.

Comment: It would be simpler to answer this if you could propose how you would *like* to write the code without a cast, bearing in mind that the compile-time type of `obj` is `Object`.

Comment: This is why: http://ideone.com/rQtw6W

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declared type of `obj` is `Object`, so you must cast it to tell the compiler that it is a `Dog`.

Although *logically* it can't be anything else at that point in the code, the compiler doesn't know anything about logic - it only knows about the type.

Comment: Truth be told, the compiler *could* know about it in this simple case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The compiler could do a lot of things, but one as to draw the line somewhere...

Comment: Indeed, though different languages draw the line differently. In Ceylon, for instance, the cast [would not be necessary](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.0/tour/types/).

Comment: Kotlin fixes this as well: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Smart%20casts/Task.kt

Answer (score 6):

Because you are defining your own parameters for equality, you have to make sure they are the same class. That is, unless you're comparing them the `==` way, then you need to compare some value inside the objects. To compare values inside the objects, they need to be the same type!

For example, let's say you have two `Dog`s.

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog("Fido");
Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rover");
```

If you want to test if they have the same name, as I'm sure you know, you can't use:

```
if(dog1 == dog2)
```

So you override the equals method. However, because you're overriding it, it has to have the same *method signature*. A method signature is defined by the name of the method, and the number and type of it's parameters. Which means if you wish to override it, it needs to have a parameter of type `Object`. Hence:

```
if(dog1.equals(dog2))
```

The reason you need to cast it to use whatever method you're using to get the `name` value from the dog, and compare those values.

**A note on your class design**

The convention in object oriented programming, and certainly in Java, is to have `Accessor` and `Mutator` methods to get and change variables in a class. That is:

```
dog1.name; ----> dog1.getName();
```

where `getName()` looks like:

```
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The properties `name` and `age` are specific only to `Dog`. You can't access `name` or `age` by using `obj`, which is an `Object`. For ex, the following code will generate **compile time error**:

```
this.name.equals(obj.name)
```

> I don't understand why why have to cast the reference to the Dog reference. If that reference is not of type Dog we return false. Why all the hassle with casting it ?

Because although the reference is of `Dog` it doesn't means that it is the same Dog. The name of the other dog may not be the same as your `Dog`. In order to compare the `name` and `age` of the other `Dog` with your `Dog`, it has to be cast first.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding equals method to check equality by `value` **not** by `reference`..

i.e You want two dogs equal if they have **same** `name` and `age` **not** if they are owned by the same person(i.e not if their references are equal)

---

Without cast you can't access dog's `name` and `age` members

Answer (score -1):

For JVM it is not that obvious that obj is Dog, so you have to be explicit with the cast.

Answer (score -1):

Because as method parameter `obj` is Instance of `Object` class. So in the method body you need to cast `obj` back to the `Dog` type.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your demo class is missing a hashCode() method.  The two objects can only be equal if their call to an overridden hashCode() is equal. (the same integer value).

I'm pretty sure you need both to guarantee this equation.