# Why && in return and casting?

Tags: java, casting, return, logical-operators

I was looking at the core Java book and the equality test part confused me a bit

1. What is the meaning of this specific return line, especially with the `&&`
2. Why does it need to cast `otherObject` to Employee when it already know if it's of the same class?

```
class Employee 
{
...
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        // a quick test to see if the objects are identical
        if (this == otherObject) return true;

        // must return false if the explicit parameter is null 
        if (otherObject == null) return false;

        // if the classes don't match, they can't be equal 
        if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
           return false;
        // now we know otherObject is a non-null Employee 
        Employee other = (Employee) otherObject;

        // test whether the fields have identical values 
        return name.equals(other.name)
           && salary == other.salary
           && hireDay.equals(other.hireDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: The meaning of `&&` "in" a return is the same as anywhere else that it can be used

Comment: `otherObject` is of type `Object`. It could as well be a `Cat`, not an `Employee`. At that point in the method, you made sure that it actually is an `Employee` (the `if` before). So now you would like to compare their fields, like the name and salary etc. In order to do that, you have to tell Java "*Hey, this is actually an `Employee`, trust me*". Otherwise you can not access it, because Java will try to protect you from accessing the salary of a cat, which would not work.

Comment: Since you are overriding equals, you must override hashCode.

Comment: Some languages (e.g. Kotlin and Typescript) do have control-flow type narrowing, meaning you don't need to cast in a branch where the type is guaranteed. But Java doesn't do this.

Comment: @kaya3 Not yet, but **pattern matching** will come soon, which can simplify this from two steps to one.

Comment: @NomadMaker Only if the class is going to be used with a hashing collection.

Comment: @user207421 True, but the contract states that two objects that are equal must have the same hashCode.

Comment: @NomadMaker The contract for hashing states that.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: [Casting in equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16497471)

Comment: Do you know what `&&` means in general? As in outside a return statement. If so, it's not really clear which part of the return you're having trouble with, since it means exactly the same here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a logical short-circuiting and operator. It is a shorter (and faster) way to write

```
if (name.equals(other.name)) {
    if (salary == other.salary) {
        return hireDay.equals(other.hireDay);
    }
}
return false;
```

(note that the original does not involve *branches*). As for why it needs a cast for `otherObject` to `Employee`; it is precisely because it does not know that `otherObject` is an `Employee` - in fact, you have

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
```

which means `otherObject` is an `Object` (as required by `Object.equals(Object)`). You need a cast to tell the compiler that at runtime `otherObject` **is** an `Employee` (or throw a class cast exception).

If you expected the compiler to "know" that after

```
// if the classes don't match, they can't be equal 
if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
   return false;
```

It's safe to infer `otherObject` is an `Employee`, I'm sorry to inform you Java does not make any such inference (currently). Compilers aren't sentient (despite seeming like it sometimes).

Answer (score -1):

&& is a type of Logical Operator and is read as “AND AND” or “Logical AND“. This operator is used to perform “logical AND” operation, i.e. the function similar to AND gate in digital electronics.

One thing to keep in mind is the second condition is not evaluated if the first one is false, i.e. it has a short-circuiting effect. Used extensively to test for several conditions for making a decision.

Comment: I just read it as "and".

Comment: "AND AND" would be a highly unusual way of reading `&&`, like reading the periods in "U.S.A."